# What is the use of <alloy> tags of Liferay faces in liferay 6.2?

Tags: jsf, liferay-6

What is the use of `<alloy>` tags of Liferay faces? Is it used to fetch liferay web content? How to use a `<alloy: commandButton>` tag and redirect the button to some other wanted page?

Answer (score 2):

The `<alloy>` tags provided by Liferay Faces Alloy are JSF component tags that manifest HTML markup and JavaScript for Liferay's [AlloyUI](https://alloyui.com/) framework. You can use `<alloy:commandButton>` to redirect from one JSF view to another (within the same portlet, on the same portal page) by adding "?faces-redirect=true" to the end of the value of the action attribute, or to the end of the `<to-view-id>` value in the faces-config.xml `<navigation-rule>`. You can also specify `<redirect />` in the `<navigation-rule>`. Fetching Web Content can be done via the `<portal:runtime>` component from Liferay Faces Portal. See the [Multiple Instances](http://www.liferayfaces.org/web/guest/portal-showcase/-/portal-tag/portal/runtime/multiple-instances) use-case in the showcase for details.